# Showing me error while executing this procedure in MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE Sample
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_SQLSTR VARCHAR(800);
    SET v_SQLSTR='Hi';
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

> Error Details:    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'BEGIN  DECLARE v_SQLSTR VARCHAR(800);  SET
>   v_SQLSTR='Hi'; END' at line 2

I am new in MySQL. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed the brackets. Try this:
...
CREATE PROCEDURE Sample()
...

Comment: Thank you... @Ispirer - SQLWays Migrat

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have a syntax error:

- Add `()` to your procedure's name
- Remove `;` after the `END` keyword

Change your code to:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE Sample()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_SQLSTR VARCHAR(800);
    SET v_SQLSTR='Hi';
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

To avoid further errors, you can check the official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).